# BASH commands: pkill/pgrep

Tags: bash, shell, command

I'm struggling with understanding the difference between using `pgrep`, as opposed to using `ps | grep`.
Apart from the fact that `pgrep` will only list the PID, what is the difference?

When I run an instance of kwrite in the background of my terminal, as well as opening one up using the GUI, why is the output given by `ps | grep kwrite` only one PID, when two instances of kwrite are running?

On a slightly different note, why would using `pkill` to kill a crashed instance of kwrite not be a good way of killing a process? The only explanation that I could come up with, is that it would kill all processes with the string "kwrite" in them, and that may not be only the instance of kwrite I wanted to kill.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `ps | grep` will fork 2 processes, `pgrep` only one.
2. `ps | grep whatever` may also list `grep whatever` depending when `ps` exits, `pgrep whatever` will not.
3. `ps` will need additonal command-line switches to show up both kwrite processes. (see: man ps and try ps -ef next time)

> By default, ps selects all processes with the same effective user ID (euid=EUID) as the current user and associated with the same terminal as the invoker.

Try running a handfull kwrite instances, preferably with important and unsaved data to find out, why killing the crashed one using `pkill` might not be the most clever idea.

Comment: `s/psgrep/pgrep/g` :-)